# Create Json with specific structure from two different arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, encode

I've already tried to find a solution on stack, but I didn't found a possible reply, so I decided to open a topic to ask:

Let's say we have 2 arrays: one containing "keys" and another one containing "values"

Example:

```
keys = [CO2, Blood, General, AnotherKey, ... ]
values = [[2,5,4,6],[4,5,6],[1,3,34.5,43.4],[... [
```

I have to create a Json **with a specific structure** like:

```
[{
        name: 'CO2',
        data: [2,5,4,6]
    }, {
        name: 'Blood',
        data: [4,5,6]
    }, {
        name: 'General',
        data: [1,3,34.5,43.4]
    }, {
         ...
    }, 
}]
```

I've tried to make some test bymyself, **like concatenate strings and then encode it as json**, but I don't think is the correct path to follow and a good implementation of it  ... I've also take a look on `JSON.PARSE`, `JSON.stringify`, but I never arrived at good solution so... I am asking if someone know the correct way to implements it!

EDIT:

In reality, i didn't find a solution since "name" and "data" are no strings but object

Comment: You haven't presented any solution. Have attempted to solve this yourself?

Comment: yea, as i wrote, i've tried to concat strings like `var x = "name : {key}...` but i don't think is the correct way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get your desired output:

```js
keys = ["CO2", "Blood", "General", "AnotherKey"]
values = [[2,5,4,6],[4,5,6],[1,3,34.5,43.4],[0] ]

const output = keys.map((x, i) => {
  return {"name": x, "data": values[i]}
})

console.log(output)
```

However, since you're literally constructing key/value pairs, you should consider whether an object might be a better data format to output:

```js
keys = ["CO2", "Blood", "General", "AnotherKey"]
values = [[2,5,4,6],[4,5,6],[1,3,34.5,43.4],[0] ]

const output = {}
for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  output[keys[i]] = values[i]
}

console.log(output)
```

With this data structure you can easily get the data for any keyword (e.g. `output.CO2`).  With your array structure you would need to iterate over the array every time you wanted to find something in it.

(Note: The reason you weren't getting anywhere useful by searching for JSON methods is that nothing in your question has anything to do with JSON; you're just trying to transform some data from one format to another.  JSON is a string representation of a data object.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply. I missed the brackets, and i am gonna fix that in the question too, so no one missunderstand, i am sorry for that! By the way, thank you! I was looking for the first reply you sent me ... one question, far as i read i should be able to strinfigy the object and obtain the string desired right?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` will return the JSON string representation of an object, yes.   

(Meanwhile: it's generally best not to change a question after the fact, as it can make the existing answers confusing for future users; in this case it's kind of incidental to the question, I'll edit the answer to match)

Comment: oh ... yea i'm sorry, thank you i wasn't aware about that! Thank you for the tips and the instruction, really appreciate it! Those are my firsts steps in JS!

Comment: No trouble at all, happy to help!